# how create AMP iframe adjusts its height according to the content

Tags: amp-html

Is there a way to insure that the AMP iframe adjusts its height according to the content that is inside? This content is dynamic and can change from time to time. 
Thanks

Comment: use layout responsive

Answer (score 1):

You can use the amp-iframe resizing API to trigger the amp-iframe element to resize from within the embedded document:

```
window.parent.postMessage({
  sentinel: 'amp',
  type: 'embed-size',
  height: document.body.scrollHeight
}, '*');
```

[Here is a sample implementation with documentation](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-iframe/#resizable-iframes).