# How to create amp-embed that adjusts its height according to the content?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, amp-html, amp-ad

This is similar to this question, but I need to dynamically adjust the height of an amp-embed rather than an amp-frame.

[how create AMP iframe adjusts its height according to the content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52872422/how-create-amp-iframe-adjusts-its-height-according-to-the-content)

This page gives clear examples of how to adjust the height of an amp-frame:

https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/components/amp-iframe/

When I do the same thing for an amp-embed, unfortunately it doesn't work and I haven't found similar instructions for an amp-embed or an amp-ad.

Here is the amp-frame:

```
<amp-iframe
  width="300"
  height="10"
  layout="responsive"
  sandbox="allow-scripts allow-same-origin"
  resizable
  frameborder="0"
  src="http://localhost/loader.html"
>
  <div overflow></div>
</amp-iframe>
```

And in the loader.html file, after the content is loaded, I make this call:

```
window.parent.postMessage({sentinel: 'amp', type: 'embed-size', height: document.body.scrollHeight},'*');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amp-embed and amp-ad can be resized using the requestResize API call. Here is more information:

> Ads can call the special API window.context.requestResize(width,
> height, opt_hasOverflow) to send a resize request.
>
> Once the request is processed the AMP runtime will try to accommodate
> this request as soon as possible, but it will take into account where
> the reader is currently reading, whether the scrolling is ongoing and
> any other UX or performance factors.

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/main/ads/README.md#ad-resizing